# How to draw a circle sector on an html5 canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, geometry, geometric-arc, sector

I'm trying to make a sort of pie-chart shape on a canvas element, however I can't seem to find any function that does this by itself. I only seem to be able to draw full circles and segments. Is there an easy way to do this?

(See also: [Wikipedia on circle terminology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Terminology))

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The following should work:

```
context.moveTo(cx,cy);
context.arc(cx,cy,radius,startangle,endangle);
context.lineTo(cx,cy);
context.stroke(); // or context.fill()
```

with `cx`, `cy` being the center of the arc.

Comment: Martin has the right idea, here's a working example if you're really lost: http://jsfiddle.net/3VB68/

Comment: Just a FYI, angles are in radians here.

Comment: What about `context.beginPath()` / `context.closePath()` ? Some stuff like `clearRect()` will stop working without them