# Canvas partial circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So, I have some js code to draw a circle with a specified percentage my issue is that I want the empty part to be filled in with a specified color also.
[Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCOGL.png)

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="ion.js"></script>
    <canvas data-width="5" data-ringcolor="blue" data-filledcolor="1" data-precentage="90" onclick="createNewChart( this, 40 );">
    </canvas>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function createNewChart( elemnt, radius )
{
    if( elemnt.getAttribute( "data-ringcolor" ) && elemnt.getAttribute( "data-filledcolor" )  && elemnt.getAttribute( "data-precentage" ) && elemnt.getAttribute( "data-width" ) )
    {
        var percentage = Number( elemnt.getAttribute( "data-precentage" ) );

        var ctx = elemnt.getContext( "2d" );
        ctx.beginPath( );
        ctx.arc( 95, 50, radius, 0, ( ( percentage / 100 ) * 2 ) * Math.PI );
        ctx.strokeStyle = elemnt.getAttribute( "data-ringcolor" );
        ctx.lineWidth = Number( elemnt.getAttribute( "data-width" ) );

        ctx.stroke();
    }
    else
    {
        alert( "Missing attribute!" );
    }
}
```

Comment: `degrees * Math.PI / 180` should give you the radians, I believe.

Comment: `360 * percent / 100` should give you the degrees per percent.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230363/how-to-draw-a-circle-sector-on-an-html5-canvas) may help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another path like this:

```
function createNewChart( elemnt, radius )
{
    if( elemnt.getAttribute( "data-ringcolor" ) && elemnt.getAttribute( "data-filledcolor" )  && elemnt.getAttribute( "data-precentage" ) && elemnt.getAttribute( "data-width" ) )
    {
        var percentage = Number( elemnt.getAttribute( "data-precentage" ) );

        var ctx = elemnt.getContext( "2d" );
        ctx.beginPath( );
        ctx.arc( 95, 50, radius, 0, ( ( percentage / 100 ) * 2 ) * Math.PI );
        ctx.strokeStyle = elemnt.getAttribute( "data-ringcolor" );
        ctx.lineWidth = Number( elemnt.getAttribute( "data-width" ) );

        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath( );
        ctx.arc( 95, 50, radius, ( percentage / 100 ) * 2 * Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI );
        ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
        ctx.lineWidth = Number( elemnt.getAttribute( "data-width" ) );

        ctx.stroke();
    }
    else
    {
        alert( "Missing attribute!" );
    }
}
```